# Rails: Validate attribute presence for at least one record in each group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to do something like:

```
validates :primary_product, presence: { scope: :student_id }
```

There can be multiple rows with same `student_id`. For set of all rows(with same `student_id`) at least one value of `primary_product` should be present. This does not seem to work. Not sure if I can apply scope with presence.

Comment: `validates :primary_product, if: :student_id?`? If not, can you give a more detailed elaboration?

Comment: There can be multiple rows with same `student_id`. For set of all rows atleast one value of `primary_product` should be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following, using custom validation:

```
validates :primary_product, if: -> x {
  where.not(primary_product: nil).exists?(student_id: x.student_id)
}
```